# What kind of analysis?

Tags: regression

I'm doing a research about perceptions on terrorism. I will be having 6 different stories (each story with different ethnicity and group affiliation) that I will be randomly giving to participants about the arrest of someone committing violence, and the participants will be deciding if they want to label the violence as "terrorism" or "mass shooting".

So, terrorism and mass shooting will be the dependant variables and the independent variables will be the difference between the groups (ethnicities, group affiliation and control group).

Does logistic regression sound like a fitting analysis to use?

Comment: You meant the dependent variable is binary with options "terrorism" vs. "mass shooting?" Or did you mean there are two binary dependent variables: terrorism yes/no AND mass shooting yes/no? If it's the former, you may risk some perception problem because the two choices are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: Oh Im sorry, I believe its the second one, that there are two binary dependant variables terrorism yes/no AND mass shooting yes/no for each group. There will be given questions after participants read the stories asking them what they will label this type of crime as. So my hypothesis will be for example that a certain kind of ethnicity will be more likely to be labeled as a mass shooter for the exact same crime another ethnicity will be labels as "terrorist" for.

Answer (score 1):

Logistic regression works well on binary outcomes with continuous factors. Your factors are either binary or categorical, so a decision tree may suit better.

One thing that you didn't mention in your question is whether you have characteristics of the surveyed subjects. This would probably the most important variable. If the perpetrator of shooting is from the same group as the people you ask the question, you may get different results from when they're in different groups.

Comment: So the perpetrator in one of the stories will be from the same group as the people I'm asking the questions to, as I will be looking at in-group and outgroup effects as well